# is there any process of increasing harddisk memony on dual boot?

Tags: 14.04

i am having both windows and ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my system. As i find more easier to use ubuntu i want to increase my harddisk space for my ubuntu. is there any way to do so. there is no any free parition left on my harddisk. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use separate USB stick. The one you have installed Ubuntu from is fine.
First, boot to Windows, where in System Settings - Administration there was (in Win 7) a utility to change partition sizes. Shrink Windows partition to make some room. Do not touch the Linux partitions with it!
Second, boot with Ubuntu Live medium (Usb stick, or CD or whatever), run the Gparted software (it is preinstalled in Ubuntu Live) and use in to enlarge and move Linux partitions. Gparted is not very good at handling NTFS partitions, hence the Windows action first.